# Why does file copying pause when user profile is "locked" on OSX ? (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, backup, file-transfer, file-permissions, macbook-pro

I left my MacBook Pro backing up to an external drive using SuperDuper only to wake up and find that the progress was where I had left it. I had used my hot-corners that put my **display to sleep** also requiring a password on wake-up when I left it backing up overnight.

The file copy continued after I logged back on in the morning and the hard drive began flashing showing activity. Copying resumed but this time I turned off my display using the brightness keys instead of "locking." I noticed the same thing backing up with Backblaze, and also copying from one external to the other.

What's going on it seems like file operations aren't permitted when a user is logged in but the sign-on screen is active?

Using Mac OS X Mavericks. Power Options: Computer Sleep is set to Never & Display Sleep is at 10 minutes. Put hard disks to sleep when possible is unchecked. Require Password set to after 4hrs in Security.

Comment: It can't really do much when it's asleep - that's kind of the idea of putting it to sleep. You have to keep it awake to complete a task like that.

Comment: It's not in sleep. It's locked requiring sign on. Just like Windows+L, for example music still plays and I can still control play/plause/skip on locked mode. I don't know what to call it exactly since osx doesn't have lock option

Comment: ah, OK. Then, idk, sorry. Mine never sleeps, but the screen will nod off or I can hot-corner it, but overnight tasks still continue, even if when I 'wake' it I get the logon screen.